# VBA Selenium: FindelementBy using CSS locators

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriver

Need a resource not Selenium documentation or W3C website, all there is information about Java, Python codes. I need to see how to use FindElement(By) in VBA or

```
.FindElementByCss("li > div  > a=[href]").Click
```

The most useful site with examples I found is https://endtest.io/guides/blog/2020/07/31/a-practical-guide-for-finding-elements-with-selenium/

Comment: Does that expression not work for your use-case? What HTML are you trying to parse?

Comment: I edit code with all snippets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close enough. As an example for the following HTML:

```
<li>
    <div>
        <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

To identify the desired element you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *FindElementByCss*:

  ```
  .FindElementByCss("li > div > a[href]")
  ```
- Using *FindElementByCss* (canonically):

  ```
  .FindElementByCss("li > div > a[href*='stackoverflow']")
  ```
- Using *FindElementByXPath* (canonically):

  ```
  .FindElementByXPath("//li/div/a[@href=\"https://stackoverflow.com\"]")
  ```

Comment: In my situation it is three same <li <div < a identical as in your example, for clicking the second one, I write code Xpath("section[2]/ul/li[2]/div/a"), But does not click when macros is compiling, when I put Wait(24000) then sometimes it clicks properly. It's strange. And Wait(24000) is long enough. I look to the webpage is loading in a 2 s, so why to wait 24 s for clicking availability? i couldn't get yet? what's strange I can easily click the first li >div> a item

Comment: I found the reason why, it is not clickable. View...When scrolling down the screen, it clicks easily. I will open new question thread